# How cut like 'Split' binded string in Silverlight Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a bit problem i using Generic Collection for ItemsSource in a Wrapped Listbox and i display the item.Title and after i want to display the Creating of Month without display the year

Data storing: YYYY.Month(fullname)
In C# easy `string.Split('.').Last();`

can i somehow split the binded item's string?

Comment: Use Converter in the Binding and split it in the Convert method, return back it to display...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot add additional property that would that in view model then you can create custom `IValueConverter`:

```
public class SplitConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((string)value).Split('.').Last();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

create in XAML resources:

```
<local:SplitConverter x:Key="SplitConverter"/>
```

and use it in `Binding`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=string, Converter={StaticResource SplitConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Already tried it but when try to write
.Split('.').Last()
 I no have .Last() function of string and cant do this try already with array like this   
 string[] temp=((string)value).Split('.'); 
  return temp[1]; 
  but it's still not working

Comment: do you have `using System.Linq;`?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `<Text="{Binding StringFormat=SplitConverter, Converter={StaticResource SplitConverter}} />"`
It worked for me